# GCD between Ranges

Tags: algorithm

I have given an array of size N. I have Q queries I have to calculate  gcd between L and R where  L R, where 1 ≤ L ≤ R ≤ N.
How to calculate it efficiently as brute force approach will fail .

Comment: What do you do with the array values ?

Comment: Actually GCD is reasonably fast. Can you provide some contraints? I.e. what are the expected values of N and Q?

Comment: If I understand correctly the array is for the purpose of helping you compute the GCD efficiently. What is the type of data in your array ? Can you choose it ?

Comment: gcd is associative, so you can do the usual tree-based thing (a node stores the gcd of all items in the range it covers, can be constructed simply by taking the gcd of its direct children). Then to query you need only O(log n) gcds.

Comment: Your description is a bit unclear.  If I understand correctly, for each one of the Q queries you're given an L and an R, and you need to compute gcd(L, R).  Is that correct?  @harold: it seems unlikely that the OP needs to compute the simultaneous gcd of *all* integers in a range: that gcd would always be 1 for a nontrivial range, since gcd(n, n+1) = 1.

Comment: @MarkDickinson but it's an array, not a range of integers. They could be all 42 and then the gcd of any arbitrary range will still be 42.

Comment: @harold.  Ah, maybe.  I really can't tell from the wording of the question what the OP is after.  What does "gcd between L and R" mean?

Comment: @MarkDickinson well he wrote array, no doubt about it. "gcd between L and R" just means "the gcd of all items with index between L and R", but a bit informally stated

Comment: Got it.  I hadn't thought about it that way.  Thanks.

Comment: At a guess, this is coming from http://www.codechef.com/problems/GCDQ

Answer (score 4):

Segment tree can be used to do preprocessing and query in moderate time. With segment tree, preprocessing time is O(n) and time to for GCD query is ***O(Logn)***. The extra space required is O(n) to store the segment tree.

**Representation of Segment trees**

- Leaf Nodes are the elements of the input array.
- Each internal node represents GCD of all leaves under it.

Array representation of tree is used to represent Segment Trees i.e., for each node at index i,

- Left child is at index 2*i+1
- Right child at 2*i+2 and the parent is at floor((i-1)/2).

Implementation can be found here http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gcds-of-a-given-index-ranges-in-an-array/

Answer (score 3):

GCD is additive and commutative. This means segment tree can solve this problem with log(N) time per range GCD query.

[Wikipedia has a nice article about segment trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree)

Comment: What do you mean by `additive` ?

Comment: @fjardon gcd(a, b, c) = gcd(gcd(a, b), c)

Answer (score 0):

OR use a sparse table with O(n log n) processing and O(1) per query